# Can I generate a REST service from a GraphQL schema?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, graphql, graphene-python

I'd like to build a Django app with both a GraphQL endpoint and a REST API. Maintaining both separately would be too much of a pain; I'm looking for a good way to only maintain the GraphQL service and have the REST endpoints generated automagically.

Does anyone know about a good way to do this?

I know there are ways to build a GraphQL server on top of REST endpoints, but I'd rather have it the other way around, as the REST API requirement might go away in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using Node.js, there is a library that does that (graphql2rest): https://github.com/sisense/graphql2rest

You can use it to automatically generate a REST API from your existing GraphQL schema.

"GraphQL2REST is a Node.js library that reads your GraphQL schema and a user-provided manifest file and automatically generates an Express router with fully RESTful HTTP routes — a full-fledged REST API."

Comment: It's been a while, so I'm not going to test this. Instead I'm going to accept this as an answer, assuming the library works as advertised, as it would have solved my problem back then.

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is not having a dedicated client on the client side and you can live with long urls your graphql endpoint **is** your *RESTlike* API. Disclaimer: Untested code for educational purposes only ;)

Read all posts:

```
GET /api/posts
=>
GET /graphql?query={posts{id title body}}
```

Create a post

```
POST /api/posts
{ "title": "Hello", "body": "world" }
=>
POST /graphql?query=mutation m($title:String!,$body:String!){createPost(title:$title,body:$body){id title body}
{ "variables": { "title": "Hello", "body": "world" } }
```

Your code can then work in a REST like manner (imagine redux actions calling REST APIs).

If you want something more in terms of a server, you can easily reverse what you discribed here:

> I know there are ways to build a GraphQL server on top of REST endpoints,

You can build a proxy that rewrites your REST queries to GraphQL queries. This might be much easier than mapping a REST endpoint to GraphQL since your GraphQL API is much more powerful.

Some node.js express code since I don't know any python :(

```
const Lokka = require('lokka').Lokka;
const Transport = require('lokka-transport-http').Transport;
const express = require('express');

const client = new Lokka({
  transport: new Transport('...')
});

const app = express();
app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  client.query('{posts{id title body}}').then(result => {
    res.status(200).send(result);
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(500).end(); // Or other error handling
  });
});
```

Comment: While I do like your approach, it won't work for us. The reason we want to keep REST is to make sure our clients can keep using legacy software to connect to aur APIs; any software expecting REST will break on vanilla GQL. I *could* create a facade of urls (and maybe some request/response restructuring) to mimic a REST API as you suggest, but I fear that would be even harder to maintain than just running both REST and GQL side by side.

Comment: Of cause. Performance wise this might still be a super bad idea though, especially with single resources. Assuming your app does the classic REST with cascades of resource requests your GraphQL endpoint gets a lot of load that it is not optimised for. GraphQL is a tradeoff that works better than REST because it gets rid of the limitations of REST.